# a:visited make white on "Learn more about company X"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design

When you go to a job page you can scroll down to the company area where there is a button to "Learn more about Company X".  The button forecolor text is initially white, but becomes blue when visited.  Please eliminate this style as to keep the button text white at all times.

Once visited it looks like this:
[image]

This is so bad I consider it a bug!

Actually I just checked and this is on all the blue buttons on jobs.  Even the "Apply Now" button.  I think they should have a white foreground whether or not you click the button.

Comment: We just did a big CSS-related refactor, and this regression resulted.  Looking into it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your bug report. We just did a big CSS-related refactor for Jobs, and this was a regression.

This issue has now been fixed.